# Why does Oracle SQL mysteriously resolve ambiguity in one joins and does not in others

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ambiguity

I'm an Oracle 10g user. I had to write some SQL queries, and spotted a mysterious (as I see it) behaviour. Let's pretend we have a table, which is able to join itself in some kind of simple two-level tree structure. The next query gives me "ambiguity error", which is expected:

```
select title
  from table1
    left join table1 on condition
```

BUT if I would add one more table to the join, the ambiguity problem will simply go away:

```
select title
  from table1
    join table2 on other_condition
    left join table1 on condition
```

What would be the explanation of this? I miss it completely... The full test case can be found at http://pastebin.com/webf513w

Comment: What does EXPLAIN tell you about these 2 queries?

Comment: FWIW 11g reports that field3 is ambiguously defined for all the sample queries given.

Comment: > What does EXPLAIN tell you about these 2 queries?

The first query isn't explainable since it gives "ambiguity error". For the second see http://pastebin.com/G8XvpAwJ

Comment: I've reproduced this behaviour in 10g (Express Edition 10.2.0.1.0) - the third query runs without error. 11gR1 gives ORA-00918 as expected for all three queries.

Comment: For a specific Oracle Support reference and affected versions see my answer on another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4306406/4632

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the third query, Oracle 10g returns field3 from the second TestTable1 (alias TestTable1_2). This appears to be a bug, which seems to have been fixed in 11g.

Testcase:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable1 VALUES (1,2,3,NULL);
INSERT INTO TestTable1 VALUES (2,5,6,1);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 VALUES (5,6,7);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 VALUES (2,20,30);

SELECT field3
FROM TestTable1
join TestTable2 ON TestTable1.field1 = TestTable2.field1
left join TestTable1 TestTable1_2 ON TestTable1.self_ref = TestTable1_2.id;

FIELD3
======
3
(null)

SELECT TestTable1.field3, TestTable2.field3, TestTable1_2.field3
FROM TestTable1
join TestTable2 ON TestTable1.field1 = TestTable2.field1
left join TestTable1 TestTable1_2 ON TestTable1.self_ref = TestTable1_2.id;

FIELD3 FIELD3_1 FIELD3_2
====== ======== ========
6      7        3
3      30       (null)
```

Comment: For a specific Oracle Support reference and affected versions see my answer on another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4306406/4632