# ORA-918 for ambiguous column in Oracle 9.0.2.8 but not 9.0.1?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, version, oracle9i

I'm testing an application that uses oracle 9i version 9.0.1 and no errors are raised and all queries return their results correctlty but when testing with version 9.0.2.8 for some columns the error `ORA-918 for ambiguous column` is raised.

although from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269205/why-doesnt-oracle-raise-ora-00918-column-ambiguously-defined-for-this-query?lq=1) this error should be raised only in 10.2.0.4, 10.2.0.5 and 11.1.0.6 (and not any 9i version) so why is it in 9.0.2.8 ?

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the SO post you linked to, the bug in question was fixed in 10.2.0.5 (and 10.2.0.4 Patch 2 on Windows).  It wouldn't be shocking if the fix was backported to the 9.2.0.8 patchset-- I believe 9.2 was still within the support window when the 10.2.0.4 patchset was released.

Since extended support for Oracle 10.2 ends this month and 9.2 support ended years ago, I'd be curious about why you are testing the application against a 9.2 database today.  At this point, if you're going to upgrade, it would seem likely that you'd want to upgrade to something that was still in support.  That would mean, realistically, 11.2.