# Why Oracle 10g doesn't complain about column ambiguity?

Tags: oracle, ambiguity

I'm using Oracle 10g (XE 10.2.0.1.0), and find a behavior that I don't understand:

```sql
select * 
from employees manager
    join employees worker on MANAGER.EMPLOYEE_ID = WORKER.MANAGER_ID
    join departments on DEPARTMENTS.manager_id = 108
where
    department_id = 100
;
```

The problem is I think Oracle should have complain about the ambiguity of `department_id` in the where clause, since it's a column in both the table `employees` and `departments`. The fact is in Oracle 10g, it doesn't, and the result shows that it interprets the `department_id` as the one in `departments`. However, if I comment out the second join statement (4th line above), Oracle does complain “ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined” as expected.

So, can somebody help to explain how the ambiguity is defined in Oracle 10g? Or perhaps this is a bug in 10g?

BTW: The tables are defined in the default HR schema bundled in the Oracle 10g.

Update: Just found a related post:
[Why does Oracle SQL mysteriously resolve ambiguity in one joins and does not in others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264334/why-does-oracle-sql-mysteriously-resolve-ambiguity-in-one-joins-and-does-not-in-o)

Comment: Maybe it is because it is the only one without an alias name. So everything without "<alias>." in front of is first treated to be something from departments. Do you get the ORA-Error when you give departments an alias, too?

Comment: using 11gr2 I cannot recreate this (always get ORA-00918).  Maybe try the Beta 11gR2 XE and see if you can recreate.  Sounds like a bug

Comment: @Fatal the alias doesn't solve the mystery.
`select *
from employees manager
    join employees worker on MANAGER.EMPLOYEE_ID = WORKER.MANAGER_ID
    join departments depts on depts.manager_id = 108
where
    department_id = 100
;`

Comment: @Harrison thanks. Is there a bug database of Oracle 10g that logs this bug?

Comment: When you make the join condition for departments explicit. Do you then get the error?

Comment: i dont have 10g to reproduce, but could u try with old style joins if you get ORA00918 ? `SELECT *
  FROM employees manager, employees worker, departments
 WHERE MANAGER.EMPLOYEE_ID = WORKER.MANAGER_ID
   AND DEPARTMENTS.manager_id = 108
   AND department_id = 100 ;
`

Comment: @mcha yes, 10g complains the ORA00918 ambiguity error for your query.
@Fatal I'm not sure what you mean of making the join condition explicit? could you write the query you'd like to test?

Comment: I've seen the same thing on 10g and was getting the wrong results because of it. But I didn't bother trying to find out who has the support contacts with Oracle, I just qualified the column so I would get the correct results.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN PLAN and DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR and the filter/access predicates will show which 'department_id' is being used.

Comment: This is a bug in certain versions of Oracle. For a specific Oracle Support reference and affected versions see my answer on another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4306406/4632

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it is a bug in Oracle 10g that Oracle chose not to fix. When we were upgrading our applications from 10g to 11gR2, we found a couple of queries that were written "loosely" in respect of ambiguous column names but worked in Oracle 10g. They all stopped working in 11gR2. We contacted Oracle but they pretty much said that the tolerant behavior toward ambiguous column names is a correct behavior for Oracle 10g and the stringent behavior is the correct behavior for 11g.

Comment: Correct behavior in 10g? Someone @ Oracle is blowing smoke.

Comment: @SShannon Severance: They just try to move everyone to the 11g and 11gR2. I believe starting July 1st a licensee that choses to stick with 10g will have to move to a higher level of support and, correspondingly, pay higher licensing fee.

Comment: It _is_ fixed in some versions of 10g. For a specific Oracle Support reference and affected versions see my answer on another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4306406/4632

Answer (score 1):

I think it is, because departments have no `alias`. Therefore everything without being qualified by an `<alias>.` is first treated to be from `departments`.

So I also think when you give `departments` an alias you should get the ORA-00918 again. Cannot test here though...

Comment: I just tested it, and that's not the cause, even I give an alias to departments, it shows the same result without errors.